# Is the collection of all functions between two sets a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, soft-question

Can we say "the set of all functions between two sets" as easily as we could say "the set of all real numbers", for example?

Comment: Do you mean between two specific sets, or the class of all functions?

Comment: I mean GIVEN two sets.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. This is allowed because, set theoretically, functions $A \rightarrow B$ are special subsets of $A \times B$. Sets are closed under cartesian products and comprehension allows you to take arbitrary subsets (as long as you're able to specify the membership condition in your logic).

Comment: Wait, but this only proves that a _particular_ function is a set, not the collection of all of them, doesn't it?